# Wordpress URL rewrite not working/registering

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to get my head around Wordpress URL rewrites, but I'm having no luck.

What I want to do:

I building a custom plugin where a user can build products from various options. The options collectively build a code which refers to the unique product the customer has built.

The code might be something like `140-3-WPA-ABC-2.`

The plugin will appear on a single dedicated page:

```
http://wordpress-site/configurator/
```

I want a customer with a prexisiting code to be able to enter it into the url like this:

```
http://wordpress-site/configurator/140-3-WPA-ABC-2/
```

Whereupon, the plugin gets the variable, and uses it to build the correct product.

Problem

It should be fairly simply but I can't get anything to work using the Wordpress URL rewriting rules, I can't even get anything to seemingly get registered as a Wordpress query var.

I've been trying the following in the main plugin initialisation code:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'conf_query_vars' );
add_action( 'init', 'cong_rewrites' );

function conf_query_vars($query_vars){
    $query_vars[] = 'product_code';
    return $query_vars;
}

function conf_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'configurator/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?product_code=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

If I then try and open `http://wordpress-site/configurator/140-3-WPA-ABC-2/` I get a page not found error. Echoing query_vars seems to show the variable 'product_code' is not created.

ps I've tried flushing the rewrite cache. Apologies for cross-posting to Wordpress.stackexchange.com - but seems programming question better here?

Comment: this probably belongs on the WordPress StackExchange http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hey - I sometime have problems with wordpress rewrites. You might need to "flush" the permalinks - i.e. just go and click "save" on the permalinks settings page. See if that fixes it. let me know if it does I'll find some code that will do that automatically when your plugin is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I had the same problem.

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('sponsor', EP_ALL);
});

add_filter('request', function($args) {
    print_r($args);
    return $args;
});
```

I think you should just integrate the function add_rewrite_endpoint.